# How to use preprocessor IF on DEFINE that is an ENUM member?

Tags: c++, preprocessor, c++03

I am struggling with this for a while now, and cant get it to work!

I have a preprocessor define for LOG_LEVEL which defines what logs my program should emit.
I Have a lot of LOG points, so performance is needed,
therefore, no use of runtime check for log_level.

I trimmed my code to the minimal problematic construct which can be played with (here)[https://onlinegdb.com/u39ueqNAI]:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


typedef enum {
    LOG_SILENT=0,
    LOG_ERROR,
    LOG_WARNING,
    LOG_INFO,
    LOG_DEBUG
} E_LOG_LEVELS;

// this define is set using -DLOG_LEVEL=LOG_WARNING to the compiler.
#define LOG_LEVEL LOG_WARNING


int main() {
    std::cout << "Logging Level Value is " << LOG_LEVEL << std::endl; // output 2 (correctly)
    
    #if LOG_LEVEL==LOG_WARNING
    std::cout << "Log Level Warning!" << std::endl; // outputs (correctly)
    #endif
    
    #if LOG_LEVEL==LOG_ERROR
    std::cout << "Log Level Error!" << std::endl; // outputs (Why ??? )
    #endif
    
    return 0;
}
```

The main issue is that the #if LOG_LEVEL==LOG_*  always true.

I also tried `#if LOG_LEVEL==2` but this returned FALSE  (uff).

what's going on ?

how can I test that a define is an enum value ?

Comment: You can't. The preprocessor can't know enum values.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo But the preprocessor does know macros, and `LOG_LEVEL` is a macro

Comment: C and C++ are different programming languages, please edit your tags.

Comment: Don't try to abuse the preprocessor. Also, C and C++ are different languages. Do not tag C for C++ (and vice versa)

Comment: Newsflash: compilers can optimise. Ditch the preprocessor, use a normal `if` or `if constexpr`. You are not going to see any performance degradation.

Comment: Seems like you have the XY-problem. Why is `if constexpr` not ok for you?

Comment: Avoid the use of the preprocessor, if you can. It's not hard to simply make `LOG_LEVEL` a `constexpr` variable. The thing you may not be able to avoid without using macros is side effects when determining the information to print, but those would probably be function-like macros: `#define WARN(x) do { if constexpr (LOG_LEVEL <= LOG_WARNING) { x; } } while(false)`

Comment: BTW you are reinventing the wheel, you can use existing logging library. For example - [boost log](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: The preprocessing token `LOG_LEVEL` is defined to be `LOG_WARNING`. The preprocessing token `LOG_WARNING` has no definition (because there is no `#define LOG_WARNING XXX`), so its value in any arithmetic expression is 0. So the value of `LOG_LEVEL` is also 0. And, since the preprocessing token `LOG_ERROR` is not defined, its value in any arithmetic expression is 0. So `LOG_LEVEL == LOG_ERROR` is true, as is `LOG_LEVEL == LOG_WARNING`. The preprocessor isn't as smart as you would like it to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the preprocessor for this.  A normal

```
if (LOG_LEVEL <= LOG_WARNING)
```

will not create a runtime test when the condition involves only constants and the build has any optimization at all.

Modern C++ allows you to force the compiler to implement the conditional at compile-time, using `if constexpr (...)`.  This will prune away dead branches even with optimization disabled.

---

Finally, if you insist on using the preprocessor, and you can guarantee that the macro will use the symbolic name (you'll never build with `g++ -DLOG_LEVEL=2`), then you can

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRINGY2(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define PP_LOG_LEVEL STRINGY2(LOG_LEVEL)
#define LOG_LEVEL_IS(x) STRINGY2(LOG_LEVEL)==STRINGIFY(x)
```

then either

```
#if PP_LOG_LEVEL=="LOG_WARNING"
```

or

```
#if PP_LOG_LEVEL_IS(LOG_WARNING)
```

But I would recommend avoiding preprocessor string comparison for this.

If you do use the preprocessor, I recommend checking the actual value against a whitelist and using `#error` to stop the build in case `LOG_LEVEL` isn't set to any of the approved names.

Comment: I am using VxWorks 6.9 which uses legacy compiler with C++ std'01, so constexpr is out of the question.  But your point on optimization is valid, I didn't check the actual code produced.

Comment: @TomerW: You should tag your question with `c++98` or `c++03` (there is no 2001 C++ standard) to indicate the restrictions of your compiler.